# Почему не работает сложение больших и малых чисел с плавающей точкой?

Tags: c++, арифметика, числа-с-плавающей-точкой, точность

В общем решаю задачу и не пойму почему при командах A и D координаты не изменяются.

> Начальные координаты (x = 0,001 а.с.; y = 0). Тем не менее, необходимо учитывать координаты с точностью до метра. Напишите программу для управления, где каждое нажатие W, S, A или D изменяет соответствующую координату на 1 метр. (1 а. е. — единица измерения расстояния, приблизительно равна 1.496e+11 метров). Координаты должны выводиться в метрах.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  float au = 149597870700.0;
  string step;
  string north = "W";
  string south = "S";
  string west = "A";
  string east = "D";

  float x = 1.0e-3 * au;
  float y = 0.0f * au;
  
  while (true)
  {
      cout << "Марсаход находится на позиции " << x << ", " << y << ", введите команду: ";
      cin >> step;
      if (step == "W") y += 6.684e-12;
      else if (step == "S") y -= 6.684e-12;
      else if (step == "A") x -= 6.684e-12;
      else if (step == "D") x += 6.684e-12;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: У float точность 1e-7, а вы пытаетесь вычитать 6e-12. Ну и непонятно зачем хранить координаты в а.е. если все вычисления и результат нужны в метрах.

Comment: Так, погодите. У вас же x и y уже в метрах. Так что прибавлять/вычитать нужно 1, а не 6e-12

Comment: Всегда используйте `double`. `float` нужен только в очень специальных случаях, до которых вы дойдёте очень и очень не скоро.

Comment: ваша проблема называется arithmetic underflow, посмотрите в википедии

Comment: :) подозреваю, что проблема такая (если это x86/x64) только при компиляции Debug, а в Release заработает, т.к. вычисления оптимизатор перенесёт в регистры, а они 80-разрядные и для float и для double

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте прикинем... Итак, значение x примерно 1.496e+8. Значение изменения порядка 7e-12. Т.е. вы суммириует (распишем полностью:

```
149600000.000000000000
        0.000000000007
```

Т.е. чтобы увидеть результат, нужна точность представления числа в 20 знаков. Просто прикиньте, если бы это были целые числа - сколько битов бы потребовалось для хранения 20-значного числа? Даже 64 не хватило бы. Т.е. даже `double` с этим [не справился бы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8#:%7E:text=%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D1%81%20%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%20%D1%81%2015%2D17%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%20(%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%2016%2C3)%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D1%82%2010%E2%88%92308%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%2010308.). А уж `float`...

Вот что пишут в Википедии о `double`Ж

> Числа двойной точности с плавающей запятой эквивалентны по точности числу с 15-17 значащими десятичными цифрами (в среднем 16,3) в диапазоне примерно от 10<sup>−308</sup> до 10<sup>308</sup>.

А вот о `float`:

> Числа одинарной точности с плавающей запятой эквивалентны по точности числу с 7-8 значащими десятичными цифрами (в среднем 7,6) в диапазоне от 10<sup>-38</sup> до примерно 10<sup>38</sup>.

Как видите, до 20 тут очень далеко.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую разобраться